# Swift - How to add more buttons using KCFloatingActionButton (CocoaPod)

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to use this cocoapod.

https://github.com/kciter/KCFloatingActionButton

I can create a new instance of a button, but it completely overlaps the button at the bottom? I wish to have a few buttons above one another. I have tried everything I could. However, no luck.

Could someone please explain/show how I can do this? I've followed the example and managed to use one successfully, but I am struggling to add another instance of a button.

Thank you.

Comment: Where's your code? Please show what you've tried. Also, read [Ask]

Comment: can you show how it looks like after implementation

Comment: I've deleted the code. However, it's essentially covering the first button. I will post the code which I have imported into my file.

Comment: @AshleyMills The code is over 3000 character. I cannot post it.

Comment: Don't just add all your code, just what is _relevant_ . You need to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

In the `KCFloatingActionButton.swift` file there are two properties: `paddingX` and `paddingY`. These determine the spacing from the bottom right corner.
So when you create your new button, set something like:

```
var fab = KCFloatingActionButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fab.paddingX = 150
    fab.paddingY = 150
    layoutFAB()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulellah problem is solved only copy and paste code

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        layoutFAB()
    }

    func layoutFAB() {
        let item = KCFloatingActionButton()
        item.buttonColor = UIColor(red: 188/255, green: 46/255, blue: 35/255, alpha: 1)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let Fab = KCFloatingActionButton()

        Fab.addItem("aa", icon: UIImage(named: "aa")){ item in
           print("aa")
        }


        }
        Fab.addItem("a", icon: UIImage(named: "a")){ item in

           print("a")
        }

        self.view.addSubview(Fab)
    }
```